# Possible MTU issues over OpenVPN causing SSH to fail

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I recently moved away from using OpenVPNAS to use the community edition so I can have more concurrent connections without a license.  I have the server away from me but I am on a WiFi network with two devices connected which cannot communicate with each other.  They are both connected to the same OpenVPN server using TCP and I can ping the other device from my laptop but I cannot SSH into it, it stops on

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

I've looked up this issue and have tried connecting with:

```
ssh -m umac-64-etm@openssh.com -c aes256-ctr user@ip
```

but that fails in the same spot too.

I've tried pinging it from both my laptop and the OpenVPN server itself and any packet over 250 bytes fails to send to the device. This is an insanely low packet size and I believe that this might be the issue but even setting the mssfix to 150 and the tun-mtu to 200 doesn't fix the issue even though that is far below the size of packets it can receive / return.

I'm out of ideas for fixing this and don't know where to go because every solution I've spent the last 2 hours trying to implement does not work.

At the very least, the device is functional as it runs a webserver that controls relays and the data it's sending and receiving appears to be small enough in size to work.

Comment: You are right in saying the initial symptoms sound like an MTU problem. And when faced with a possible MTU problem it is very sensible to try and establish what the MTU actually is. I agree 250 is ridiculously low, but assuming you are using IPv4 it is still a valid MTU. The lowest MTU permitted in IPv4 is 68 bytes. In IPv6 that was increased from 68 bytes to 1280 bytes. Once you have established a supported MTU you can try reducing the MTU on the first hop or reducing MSS to work around the problem. That far you have done all the right things.

Comment: The next question then of course is, why it still doesn't work. Depending on where and how you tweak MSS and/or MTU you might only fix the problem in one direction. If you somehow fixed the problem in one direction but not the other, then that could explain why it still doesn't work. Packet captures at strategic points on the network may help identify what is happening. In your setup there are 8 particular interesting places to look at packet captures.

Comment: Each of the VPN clients has a VPN connection to the server, so that's 2 VPN connections. Each VPN connection has two endpoints so that's 4 VPN endpoints. And for each of those VPN endpoints it's interesting to look at packet captures on both physical and virtual interfaces, so that's 8 places to look at packet captures. On the VPN server some of these may coincide, and it might be difficult to capture from both endpoints simultaneously when you don't have a reliable ssh connection between them. But you will still have enough options to capture traffic which will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: The main issue is that the system I'm trying to ssh into is a raspberry pi that I cannot really connect a monitor to or ssh into directly.  I might try doing the usb to ethernet because that didn't occur to me until now because I had been grinding at the issue for several hours. I attempted to fix the MSS by sending "push" commands to that client specifically when it connected and it seemed to not do much but no errors or warnings were thrown in the OpenVPN log.  The worst part is that both my laptop and the pi are connected to the same apartment wifi but traffic isn't routed between them.